# java Nested If or single if

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a basic doubt regarding the execution of the following code block (Sample):

```
String version = computer.getSoundcard().getUSB().getVersion();
```

Which might throw `NullPointerException` if `Soundcard` isn't there.

So I have ,

**Option 1 :**

```
if(computer!=null && 
        computer.getSoundCard() !=null && 
                 computer.getSoundCard().getUSB()!=null) {
   version = computer.getSoundcard().getUSB().getVersion();
}
```

**Option 2 :**

```
if(computer !=null){
   SoundCard sc = computer.getSoundCard();
   if(sc!=null){
      USB usb = sc.getUSB();
      if(usb!=null){
         version = usb.getVersion();
      }
   }
}
```

As per my understanding the **Option 1** will have extra overhead as it has to evaluate the same expression multiple times like `computer.getSoundCard()`  3 times, `computer.getSoundCard().getUSB()` 2 times.

Is my understanding correct ?

**EDIT 1:** Changed Option 2 from

```
version = computer.getSoundcard().getUSB().getVersion();
```

Comment: Can you to use Java 8 on your project... If yes, look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: I did see that and unfortunately i have to use lower version of java also i want to understand which of these is better and why.

Comment: They are both good. I'd usually go with option 1 because it's more concise. Option 2 might be better if 1) you change to `version = usb.getVersion()`, and 2) any of the getter methods might be slow.

Comment: and... java compiler will to optimize that kind of tasks... try to look at generated jvm code for your code... it's more optimized than you thought.

Comment: Assuming these methods return reference to objects (or null) - the performance penalty for calling the same getter twice is negligible. That said, if you're performing *heavy* computation inside any of these methods - that's indeed something to consider.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for pointing out the problem with 2 so are you saying that evaluating the same expression multiple times doesn't add significant/no amount of overhead.

Comment: @Deva Getter methods are usually just returning a field, so cost is nil. *Usually*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> As per my understanding the Option 1 will have extra overhead as it has to evaluate the same expression multiple times

Yes, these calls would be made multiple times. However, you can shorten it if you make assignments as part of your conditional, like this:

```
SoundCard sc;
USB usb;
if(computer != null && (sc = computer.getSoundCard()) != null && (usb = sc.getUSB()) != null) {
    version = usb.getVersion();
}
```

Note that references to `sc` and `usb` inside the expression and inside the conditional are safe, because `&&` evaluation is guaranteed to stop upon reaching the first `false` in the chain.

Comment: Just to add: You should realize that you are defining those variables `sc` and `usb` in a much wider scope as you might need. I would not want to read an if expression like this in my source code.

Answer (score 24):

A better approach is to extract this USB-version-getting code into another single method, say `getComputerUsbVersion()`, then flatten the super long `if` or the nested `if-else` block into several simple `if` blocks:

```java
public String getComputerUsbVersion(Computer computer) {

    if (computer == null)  return null; 

    SoundCard soundCard = computer.getSoundCard();
    if (soundCard == null) return null; 

    USB usb = soundCard.getUSB()
    if (usb == null) return null;

    return usb.getVersion();
}
```

As you can see, the code is much cleaner and easy to understand, the super long `if` condition or the nested `if-else` block is also avoided. You can even add more condition checking code to this method later on very easily.

Comment: I agree because this form will encapsulate the logic to get the usb version. Well, the function name could be more specific, like findSoundCardUsbVersion... "find", not "get", because get presumes with it exists... and there are many points of return on the method.

Comment: Even better would be to raise an exception (and log an error) when null is found.